# How to restrict some controller ActionResults,so they are only avaliabe to logged in users using AuthorizeAttribute? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a login view and then if user is logged in,it would be able to access upload page,but if he is not logged in then he should not be able to access that page? I tried with AuthorizeAttribute,but i don't really understand how app will know when user is logged in and when it is not?

This is the log in method in the controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(userLogin login)
        {
            string message = "";

            using (DbBaza dc = new DbBaza())
            {

                var v = dc.userInfo.Where(a => a.Email == login.Email).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {




                    if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(login.password), v.Password) == 0)
                    {

                        Response.Write("Login succesful");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return Content("login unsuccesful");
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    message = "Invalid credential provided";
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: To use `AuthorizeAttribute` you should use [ASP.NET identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) or populate the authentication cookie using some custom method. The application then uses this cookie for authorization.

Comment: Just use the `AuthorizeAttribute` and use the .Net identity roles. If someone who isn't in one of the roles tries to access the controller action, it will not let them